# Is the charateristic function $\chi _{\Omega }$ in the Sobolev space $W^{1,2}_{0}(\Omega)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, sobolev-spaces

Given $\Omega$ is a bounded, $C^1$ domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$. $\chi _{\Omega }(x)$ is the characteristic function of $\Omega$.

I have done the followings:

We can get $\chi _{\Omega }(x) \in L^2(\Omega)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ quite easily. The next thing is to show the existence of the weak derivative of $\chi_{\Omega}$.

For $n=1$, $\Omega$ is an open interval. Let $\phi \in C_{c}^{\infty }(\Omega)$ be an arbitrary test function. We have

$\int_{a}^{b}\chi _{(a,b) }\phi 'dx=\int_{a}^{b}\phi'dx =\phi(b)-\phi(a)=0$

So $\int_{a}^{b}\chi _{(a,b) }\phi 'dx=-\int_{a}^{b}0.\phi dx$, and the weak derivative of $\chi_{\Omega}$ is $0$.

For $n\geq 2$, I get stuck and don't know if $\chi_{\Omega}$ has the weak derivative or not.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: $\chi_\Omega$ is the same as just $1$ as far as $\Omega$ is concerned, so its weak derivative is its strong derivative which is $0$. But it won't be $W^{1,p}_0$ because it isn't compactly supported.

Comment: @Ian: I didn't get why it's not compactly supported. I think $supp\chi_{\Omega}=\overline{\left \{ x\in\mathbb{R}^n: f(x)\neq 0 \right \}}=\overline{\Omega}$, which is a compact set. Am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: It means that it is compactly supported as a subset of $\Omega$. $\chi_\Omega$ does not have that property, because its support *inside* $\Omega$ is $\Omega$ itself which is not compact.

Comment: OK thank you, I got it.

Comment: @Ian it is misleading to say that it is not in $W_0^{1,2}$ because it is not compactly supported. Consider the function $x(x-1)$ which is in $W_0^{1,2}((0,1))$ but is not compactly supported in $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 6):

**No**, the function $\chi_\Omega$ is not in the Sobolev space $W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$
if the domain $\Omega$ is bounded.

Recall that $W_0^{1,2}$ is defined as the closure of the subspace $C_c^\infty(\Omega)\subset H^1(\Omega)$.
Let us assume that $\chi_\Omega\in W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$.
Then there exists a sequence $\phi_n\in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$
such that $\phi_n\to \chi_\Omega$ in $W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$.
It follows that
$$
\|\phi_n\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\to \|\chi_\Omega\|_{L^2(\Omega)}=|\Omega|>0
$$
and
$$
\|\nabla \phi_n\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\to \|\nabla\chi_\Omega\|_{L^2(\Omega)}=0.
$$
(Note that the function $\chi_\Omega$ has weak derivatives $0$
because it is equal to the classical derivative and $\chi_\Omega$ is constant.)

However, by the [Poincaré inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_inequality)
we have
$$
\|\phi_n\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq C\|\nabla\phi_n\|_{L^2(\Omega)}
$$
for some constant $C>0$ (here it is useful that the domain $\Omega$ is bounded).
This yields a contradiction to the convergences that are mentioned above.